# Craft CMS 4 custom orderBy

Tags: craft4, sorting

Is there a way to sort entries by a customSortOrderFunction in a plugin?

Like: `craft.entries.section('somename').orderBy(myCustomSortOrderFunction)`

Where `myCustomSortOrderFunction` returns some data from another table.

Any suggestion or article, etc. will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to express the sorting logic in PHP, since that requires loading *all* results and then running them through the sorting function. If you have 10,000 entries and need the first 20 (according to your sort function), you're still going to load 10,000 entries and then throw out 9,980 of them.

Instead, you need to specify the sorting logic in the entry query, so the database can return the results in the correct sort order, and only return the number of results you need.

The [`orderBy` method](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-elements-db-elementquery.html#method-orderby) can take multiple forms. You can specify a single field or multiple fields in array notation, as well as the sort order (ascending or descending) for every field.

If that is not enough, you can use an [expression](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expressioninterface) to specify a custom sort function in plain SQL. You can create an expression in Twig using the [`expression` function](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/functions.html#expression):

```twig
{% set result = craft.entries()
    .section('somename')
    .orderBy(expression('your expression here'))
    .all()
%}
```